How to solve AUTO-FOX Divide by Zero Error?
I am trying to get the Radial and Angular Distribution Functions (RDF, ADF) from the AUTO-FOX package.
from FOX import MultiMolecule, example_xyz

sys = MultiMolecule.from_xyz(r'C:\Users\bnzmi\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Lustig Lab\RDF Attempts\hybrid7-pos-1.xyz')

rdf = sys.init_rdf(atom_subset=('Al', 'C', 'O'))
adf = sys.init_adf(r_max=13, weight=None, atom_subset=('O',))
adf_weighted = sys.init_adf(r_max=13, atom_subset=('O',))

rdf.plot(title='RDF')
adf.plot(title='ADF')
adf_weighted.plot(title='Distance-weighted ADF')

When I run this script, I get this error message:
[rest of the directory path]\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\FOX\functions\rdf.py:103: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in divide
  dens_mean = dist_shape[2] / ((4/3) * np.pi * (0.5 * dist.max(axis=(1, 2)))**3)


I consulted the documentation (https://auto-fox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/1_rdf.html), but could not really understand what the issue is. I have a script checking the positions of all my atoms in the system, and none of them are close to zero (the shortest distance is around 1.5 A).

I am also wondering if, like in this thread (Keep getting divide by zero error), my issue is not using floats. How does that apply to my code?


I tried to print my "sys", and all of the elements in it seem to be floats? See below
    [[[ 7.25600514  8.72794805 12.02820221]
      [14.95928393  7.84438621 11.64682185]
      [10.96354716 11.067581    8.55290687]
      [13.90091624 15.56398689  8.76734726]
      [16.80418492 13.57377941  9.60267977]
      [ 6.33053393 15.84933413  2.60828572]
      [ 8.21413187 13.2309031   2.91318796]
      [ 8.93575675 16.15589859  2.44320707]
      [12.40698335  7.84374698  2.77464373]
      [11.92339275 11.34323094 11.80519698]
      [ 7.52861562  7.56520827  9.78788325]
      [13.10538581  6.73522015 13.76295514]
      [10.82989723 12.10437062 10.06084028]
      [12.87908469  5.32888489  8.22080132]
      [ 1.07778236  3.09234291  7.15402912]
      [11.63654902  5.60199583  5.58738808]
      [-0.53486586 -2.17915618  2.59191956]
      [10.4356729   6.42491477 -4.42810484]
      [ 6.95128157  3.39314284  3.37684836]
      [16.97975178  6.60982909 10.6174393 ]
      [10.95329605  1.27074336  4.52390992]
      [12.78397904  3.05412743  7.09692838]
      [12.33656654 -0.65409041  3.08627917]
      [13.65578941 -2.15069691 -0.16165908]
      [-3.27092597 11.92237014  1.83463317]
      [-0.70312332 10.78231393 16.58499829]
      [ 6.72650307  6.72909033  5.89401978]
      [ 6.77745953 17.59925813  5.79215546]
      [ 8.18637451 15.31592535  6.88374314]
      [10.62893379  5.7730726   1.53417611]
      [ 8.09091963  8.34391673  3.42659414]
      [ 9.28725088 10.65364402  2.57004451]
      [ 9.68928304  8.9113796  -2.40555176]
      [ 0.12624191 10.68564384 -5.81805456]
      [ 6.95518149  9.61098255 14.58827988]
      [ 1.34611275  6.57618174 14.35029969]
      [ 7.43603734  4.32365274  7.0977121 ]
      [ 5.64086131  8.31555877  7.7967102 ]
      [ 6.49595398  7.75162723  4.2642536 ]
      [ 2.99617441  2.12574957  9.26036517]
      [ 9.89495245  3.3401569   4.96679085]
      [ 5.32812313  7.77853996  3.58329398]
      [ 8.90244357  5.55354152  3.44017076]
      [ 3.98327179  8.70742134  2.4366657 ]
      [ 7.99312455  5.80399956 12.53134304]
      [ 4.80430815  3.6943093   6.22870122]
      [ 3.79232246 -0.26922842  7.11844103]
      [ 0.2173818  -0.18838547  4.90822017]
      [ 6.72185774  2.32004651  0.57268472]
      [ 5.34912678 15.38046439  8.50277079]
      [-1.66035381 10.66112395  9.72699782]
      [ 1.38628949 12.2795194   2.9465908 ]
      [ 1.79612442  9.38067778  4.49232811]
      [ 3.45818308 13.71276208  1.42855228]
      [-2.95126372  8.42249247 10.882055  ]
      [ 3.37256262  9.23874181  9.09710981]
      [ 1.42387917  7.15022174  5.21559012]
      [-0.3821581   2.22427304  5.02820014]
      [ 2.92760917  5.93451299  3.44801565]
      [ 3.35133044  0.67449708 12.96943685]
      [ 2.80663569  3.07975794 12.07405559]
      [ 2.73693849  5.37196875  6.55851118]
      [ 6.48900074 19.04488274 11.43837073]
      [ 4.61299704 15.57958535 10.99807735]
      [-0.42402647 16.55842749 11.79872831]
      [13.69741641  6.05368799 16.70948865]
      [10.59075766  1.04084036  7.31630451]
      [ 5.78341624  2.39498415  9.49620596]]]
)

I would love some input! Thank you kindly!

You showed us sys, but the division in that statement is by dist.  What's in there?

Hello @TimRoberts, thank you for your response! I just checked the git documentation RDF and I am honestly a little confused. It is defined under Parameters.

I am a also a little confused by dist.max appearing in the error (and line 103 in the Git link I sent in the comments). "max" is not defined as a parameter of dist under Parameters the way that "shape" is:
dist : :class:np.ndarray[np.float64] <numpy.ndarray>, shape :math:(m, n, k)         A 3D array representing :math:m distance matrices of :math:n by :math:k atoms.

If you print sys.atoms, does it include the elements you've asked for?

@TimRober it prints the element name followed by an array with the atom id that it corresponds to. e.g. Al is atoms 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, (...), Oxygen is atom 5, 9, etc. (out of 68 atoms total).

@TimRoberts , sorry, the name got cut off above!

FWIW, max is a method of all numpy arrays.  What this seems to be saying is that the maximum distance is 0.  Is there more than one C atom?  You may need to print dist and see what it contains.

Hi @TimRoberts, thank you for your explanation!
dist is not defined. I managed to print MultiMolecule.get_dist_mat(sys)(Doc). See what it printed in the comment below.
I also printed the maximum value of that array, and it turned out to be ~26, so definitely not zero. There seem to be zeroes in the matrix below, so I am a little confused.

[[[ 0.          7.76315893  5.59441042 ...  8.39987433  9.61322938     6.97753215]   [ 7.76315893  0.          5.99393083 ...  5.5162945   9.17200296    10.88658253]   [ 5.59441042  5.99393083  0.         ...  9.95705733 10.10958384    10.14581223]   ...   [ 8.39987433  5.5162945   9.95705733 ...  0.         11.09107201    11.31587202]   [ 9.61322938  9.17200296 10.10958384 ... 11.09107201  0.     5.44942265]   [ 6.97753215 10.88658253 10.14581223 ... 11.31587202  5.44942265     0.        ]]]

This is a distance matrix, showing distances between atoms.  It's symmetric about the diagonal, which is always 0, since an atom tends to be very close to itself.  I don't know, you may need to put debugging code inside the module to get any further.

Thank you, @TimRoberts! Would it be okay if I messaged you or posted updates at some point? I am pretty lost - nobody seems to be active on the AUTO-FOX Git or other forums.

I don't know that package at all.  Like 80% of the answers I post, I just used Google and a peek at the code base.

I just thought I would give an update.
I tried out an example offered on the Git page of the package (so, one which I knew was correct without doubt), and it only worked once I added plt.show() at the end. I am still getting the error I reported in the post (divide by zero) as I have zero diagonal elements in my matrix, but the RDF/ADF plots are finally showing and are plausible.

This answer effectively addresses the issue of encountering a "divide by zero" error when using AUTO-FOX. It highlights a practical solution by suggesting to add plt.show() at the end, which resolves the problem of not displaying RDF/ADF plots despite correct implementation from the package's Git page. It acknowledges the ongoing error related to zero diagonal elements in the matrix, while emphasizing the successful visualization of plausible plots.

Adding on to my previous comment - yes, my plots started showing once I added plt.show(), but the reason why I was getting a Divide by Zero error is that I was only using the final set of coordinates I got from my simulations, instead of the xyz file with all the coordinates (one for every timestep). Now my plots are smoothed and I am not getting an error anymore.
